# How to Add ListView Items and Print the Value of It

Tags: vba

i click command button so i can add the listview items, the list view items comes from the command box and i want to msgbox it or print it on the label

this is for educational purposes

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

List1.AddItem (Combo1.Text)
If List1.ListCount > 2 Then
       MsgBox "error"
      Else
      MsgBox 'add the 3  number and print it out
End If
End Sub
```

i expect that the 3 number in the list view would add together to print the value in a form of messagebox

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim tempSum As Long
  Dim i As Long

    List1.AddItem (Combo1.Text)
    If List1.ListCount = 3 Then

          For i = 0 To List1.ListCount - 1
            tempSum = tempSum + List1.List(i)
          Next
          MsgBox "Sum of list: " & tempSum
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: why list1.listcount  has  - 1

Comment: @ShauiosbhaoiuAousiguosba  The ListIndex property contains an index of the selected row in a list. Values of ListIndex range from -1 to one less than the total number of rows in a list (that is, ListCount - 1). When no rows are selected, ListIndex returns -1.

Comment: this is wrong i want to add the sum of the 3 numbers that are in the listbox

Comment: @ShauiosbhaoiuAousiguosba I made it simple for you. See my updated answer.

Comment: @ShauiosbhaoiuAousiguosba Did you give it a try?

Comment: Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim tempSum As Long
  Dim i As Long

    List1.AddItem (Combo1.Text)
    If List1.ListCount < 3 Then
        MsgBox "need 3 numbers"
       
        Else
    If List1.ListCount = 3 Then

          For i = 0 To List1.ListCount - 1
            tempSum = tempSum + List1.List(i)
          Next
          MsgBox "Sum of list: " & tempSum
    End If
    End If
End Sub

Comment: i finished this thanks to your code i posted the right code

Comment: @ShauiosbhaoiuAousiguosba  You should post that as answer so that it will be helpful for other readers. Goodluck!